# MVC Catch-All route is the only defined route, but it gives me 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is my Register method for routes in my web API project

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AllRoutes",
    routeTemplate: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "IncomingRequest", action = "ProcessRequest" });
```

I would expect everything to go my ProcessRequest method on my IncomingRequest controller. However all routes result in 404. e.g.

`http://localhost/CatCatcher/Cat/3`

Can anyone advise what I might have missed?

Comment: Do you have another route config? There us usually a `RouteConfig.cs` where the normal MVC routes are configured. Web api is usually registered with `api/{...}` to avoid conflicting with the routes registered there. (They all end up in the same route table). Check to make sure that your MVC routes are not causing your Web Api routes to fail.

Comment: There are no other routes in the config. I am trying to route API stuff so perhaps I need to modify?

Comment: Show the `IncomingRequest ` controller. make sure it inherits from `ApiController` and not `Controller`. You may be mixing up your configuration. Also show the full files for `WebApiConfig.cs` and `RouteConfig.cs` if they exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"AllRoutes",
 "{*id}",
  new { controller = "IncomingRequest", action = "ProcessRequest", id = "" }
);
```

Sorry, i've tested it now....

Comment: I've edited answer. Sorry for mislead, I've tried this now, and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

In web API project you cant set routes by different ways like:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Routes",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And to achieve URL ("http://localhost/CatCatcher/Cat/3") you can set route prefix on controller and action also Here is example for that:

```
[RoutePrefix("CatCatcher")]
public class CatCatcherController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Cat")]
    public object Cat(int Id){
    //Do something
    }

}
```

And if you want to go on Execution before hitting Action then lets follow the example in which I secure API with IP/Domain here it is:

```
public class AuthorizeIPAddressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
        {
            //Even you can do here what you want
            //Get users IP Address 
            string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

            if (!IsIpAddressValid(ipAddress.Trim()))//check allow ip
            {
                //Send back a HTTP Status code of 403 Forbidden  
                filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

After Adding this class in project you just have to do this on your controller:

```
[AuthorizeIPAddress]   
[RoutePrefix("CatCatcher")]
public class CatCatcherController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Cat")]
    public object Cat(int Id){
    //Do something
    }

}
```

Hopefully this will help you..

Comment: I want all routes to call the same, single method though